# CSS - Image is unresponsive

Tags: html, css

If you look at `www.markallanholley.com`, you’ll notice that the robot-girl image on the right isn’t responsive at all. I’ve coded what I thought was a correct way to deal with it, but I’m having no luck whatsoever. I was wondering if someone would take a look.

I’m absolutely sure that the CSS is correctly targeting the HTML because I did a little test by changing the background color to green and the background turned green. Then I erased that line of code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-size: 110%;
  font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

footer li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1fr, 10px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: 1fr, 80%, 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

.top {
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.leftsection {
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
}

.divider {
  grid-row: 2 / span 4;
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
}

.rightsection {
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  grid-column: 3 / span 1;
}

.bottom {
  grid-row: 3 / span 1;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
}

.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}


/* unvisited link */

a:link {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* visited link */

a:visited {
  color: gray;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* mouse over link */

a:hover {
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* selected link */

a:active {
  color: lightpurple;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Fonts from Google Fonts */


/*
    font-family: 'Forum', cursive;
    font-family: 'Patua One', cursive;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;

*/
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Forum&family=Patua+One&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <nav class="top">
    <img src="http://www.markallanholley.com/links/topnavbackground.jpg">
    <a href="../index.html"><img src="http://www.markallanholley.com/links/mahlogo.png"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bio.html">Bio</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="community/index.php">Community</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section class="leftsection">
    <h1>Hello and Welcome</h1>
    <br>
    <p>I’m a designer living in Central New York. This website is still being constructed. If you’d like to learn more about me and the type of work that I do, please select <a href="bio.html">Bio</a> or <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a> from the links.
      If you’ve hired me and if you want to view a work in progress, please log in using the <a href="login.html">Login</a> link. I have a Contact form for you if you select <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>, or you can email me anytime at:</p>
    <br>
    <address>
      <a href="mailto:markallanholley@gmail.com">markallanholley@gmail.com</a>
    </address>
    <br>
    <p>The Community link is just me practicing installing forum software. You’re welcome to register if you’d like, but I don’t anticipate any activity there.</p>
  </section>
  <div class="divider">
    <img src="http://www.markallanholley.com/links/verticaldivider.png" height="966" width="10">
  </div>
  <section class="rightsection">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://www.markallanholley.com/links/notarobot.jpg" alt="Sad robot looking at computer." class="responsive">
      <figcaption>"Not A Robot" 2019, Blender, Photoshop</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </section>
  <footer class="bottom">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="bio.html">Bio </a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="community/index.php">Community</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio </a></li>
      <li>&#8226; Copyright 2020 Mark Holley</li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ea0bzLqd/)

Comment: Can you make a **minimal** demo with the **actual** image?

Comment: Fiddle is missing the actual image

Comment: Your grid-templates are invalid, the problem is coming from there.

Comment: i can see google chrome that is notifying me that "grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1fr, 10px, 1fr));grid-template-rows: 1fr, 80%, 1fr;" have invalid properties

Comment: Thank you folks! I appreciate your help and I've marked an answer as correct. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of the `grid-template-columns` has an error. You can quickly see it through the browser by inspecting the `.container` class.

[image]

Here's a quick fix which may not be what you are intending, so feel free to adjust.

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 10px 1fr;
```

Here's a screenshare of it being fixed by the small adjustment.

https://www.loom.com/share/3814415fcee84b8ba3e2e043daeed029